# My Application Ionic dockerize isn't running in the browser

Tags: angular, docker, ionic-framework, containers

I'm developing an ionic study app to learn Docker.

I did all the steps to create the image:

1 - I created the Dockerfile whit scripts:

```
FROM node:18.10.0-alpine3.15
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm i
EXPOSE 4200
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

2 - In directory of Dockerfile for CMD executed **docker build -t mcd .** and then  **docker run -p 4200:4200 mcd**

3 - The application execute no errors.
But can't open application in the browser in url localhost:4200. [image]
[image]

Where's the error?

I executed the commands:

**docker run  -p 4200:4200 mcd**

**docker run -d -p 4200:4200 mcd**

**docker run mcd**

Comment: node is not a web server. You probably want something like nginx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem :)

The solution is to modify package.json and put ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200 to start